# Handsontable javascript - loading an array from server

Tags: php, javascript, json, handsontable

I would like to create a Handsontable in Javascript using an array that exists on the server side. The array has one column:

```
$table[] = "a";
$table[] = "b";
```

To load it in a Handsontable it needs to be converted into:

```
var input = [["a"],["b"]];
$("#myTable").handsontable({
data: input,
startRows: 1,
startCols: 1
};
```

In PHP I'm using JSON to encode it first:

```
<?php echo json_encode($table); ?>
```

and then getJSON or another ajax function to get it on the client side under this format, but I cannot find the correct way. Hope someone can help.

To post it I have tried
1) posting it using a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="input_field" value=<?php echo json_encode($table); ?> >
```

and get in the Ajax part with:

```
var input = $('#input_field').val();
alert(input);
```

but the alert returns: undefined, and the array {a,b} is not loaded in the Handsontable.
2) Alternatively I'm trying to use $.getJSON. In PHP:

```
$table = array();  
$table[] = array("a");
$table[] = array("b");
echo json_encode($table);
```

In Ajax:

```
jQuery.getJSON('mypage.php',function(table){
    alert(!);
});
```

The alert is not triggered and the Ajax code has an error I think because the Handsontable is not displayed.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you find an answer solves your question, accept it. You can upvote any answer, you find helpful. See also [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, you can create an array of arrays

```
$table[] = array("a");
$table[] = array("b");
echo 'var input = ' . json_encode($table) . ";\n";
```

this will give

```
var input = [["a"],["b"]];
```

No need for hidden fields or `$.getJSON()`, because this is already a javascript array, which can be fed to `handsontable`.

If you want to do it on the client side, loop through the array and build the new array from the JSON entries

```
var json = ["a", "b"];
var input = Array();
for (var i in json)
    input.push([json[i]]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWaep/)

There are two problems with the hidden field in your question, first is you must put quotes around `value="..."` and escape the quotes inside the value. The second problem is in the jQuery selector. `#input_field` looks for an element with an `id`, but not a `name`. For this to work, you must add `id="input_field"` to the hidden input.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm also stuck when I try to post the JSON object to the client. I am trying either
- with a hidden field

    <input type="hidden" name="input_field" value=<?php echo json_encode($table); ?> >
    var x = $('#input_field').val();

- either with a $.ajax() or $.getJSON()
What do you think is the best? Cheers

Comment: @user2032001 If you have the data available, when the page is sent to the client, you need neither hidden fields nor an ajax request. Just embed the data in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I would need to post the data from the server as the array is a variable in reality. Let me edit the question to give more details.

Comment: @user2032001 I have updated my answer. As I said, you don't need a hidden field or getJSON. Just create a javascript variable `input` and you're done.

Comment: Olaf, thank you very much! This worked without posting anything just create the javascript variable in the php part. I couldn't get through this without your help, thanks again.